# how to add maven plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I am new to maven. I was trying to add the maven plugin to eclipse(indigo). The problem I am facing is that when I try to add the plugin using 'Help -> Install new software' using URL http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo the download process starts and then stops with an error

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf,2.6.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ant,2.7.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.6.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.7.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.7.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.6.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.7.0.v20120127-1122
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.5.0.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.2.0.v20120130-0943
...........
...........
```

Also when I try to install the plugin using http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases  then the installation gets stuck 48% and after a long time it again displays an error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases /1.0/1.0.100.20110804-1717/plugins /org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.0.100.20110804-1717.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases /1.0/1.0.100.20110804-1717/plugins /org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.0.100.20110804-1717.jar.
Read timed out
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases /1.0/1.0.100.20110804-1717/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.0.100.20110804-1717.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases  /1.0/1.0.100.20110804-1717/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.0.100.20110804-1717.jar.
Read timed out
............
............
```

Kindly suggest if there is something wrong with the installation process I am using.

Also suggest if there is some other method to add 'maven plugin for eclipse'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check **Contact all update sites during install to find required software** option before installing m2e.